# why object field changed in api get request?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

i want test my api so i wrote test and run my test that works well.but when i run  another  irrelevant (GET) API my previous test do not work and have strange behavior

When the following code is executed from another api:

#### api1

```
query_set = (Project.objects.all()
                .annotate(
                    name=Substr(
                        Cast(TruncMonth("created_at"),
                                       output_field=CharField()), 1, 7
                    ))
                .values("name")
                .annotate(slug=Concat(V("en-"), "name"))
                .order_by("name")
                .distinct()
            )
            return Response(
                data=ProjectArchiveListSerializer(query_set, many=True).data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
```

i see this behavior from test:

#### in test of api2

```
print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))

response = self.client.get("/api/v1.0.0/projects/project/pslug-1/")        print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))
```

and object field changed like this:

#### output of api test2

```
<MultilingualQuerySet [{'slug': 'pslug-1', 'overview': 'ov-project-1', 'text': 'text-project-1', 'title': 'project-title1'}]>
<MultilingualQuerySet [{'slug': 'pslug-1', 'overview': '', 'text': '', 'title': ''}]>
```

###test for api2

```
class TestProject(APITestCase, setup):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        setup().project()
        self.project1 = Project.objects.get(slug="pslug-1")

    def test_project_with_correct_lookup_field(self):
        print("!"*100)
        print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))
        response = self.client.get("/api/v1.0.0/projects/project/pslug-1/")
        print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))
        self.assertEqual(
            response.json(),
            {
                "slug": "pslug-1",
                "cover": None,
                "title": "project-title1",
                "overview": "ov-project-1",
                "text": "text-project-1",
                "fund": 0,
                "target": None,
                "pictures": [],
                "categories": [],
                "states": [],
                "due_date": None,
            },
        )
```

this test run well until test of api1 that contain api1 from above do not run (when i comment that or use closer run test)

###test for api2

```
class TestProject(APITestCase, setup):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        setup().project()
        self.project1 = Project.objects.get(slug="pslug-1")

    def test_project_with_correct_lookup_field(self):
        print("!"*100)
        print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))
        response = self.client.get("/api/v1.0.0/projects/project/pslug-1/")
        print(Project.objects.all().values('overview','title','text',"slug"))
        self.assertEqual(
            response.json(),
            {
                "slug": "pslug-1",
                "cover": None,
                "title": "project-title1",
                "overview": "ov-project-1",
                "text": "text-project-1",
                "fund": 0,
                "target": None,
                "pictures": [],
                "categories": [],
                "states": [],
                "due_date": None,
            },
        )
```

this test run well until test of api1 that contain api1 from above do not run (when i comment that or use closer run test)

can help me why did this happen and what should I do?

Comment: It seems you forgot to mention output of api test1

Comment: would you provide more code.

Comment: Siva Sankar it is not important because i entered it just because when  this code run the Test from  another api failed and i think the output of api1 is  not important

Comment: No. What I mean was would you provide tests.py?

Comment: Siva Sankar  I put code in answer section for better understanding